# Could anyone show me a hand? About double integral of infinite interval

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

My code is:

```
h = 1.054*10^(-34)
kB = 1.38*10^(-23)
c = 3*10^(8)
d = 10^(-8)
jdc1 = 0.0005
jdc2 = 0.002
T1 = 300
T2 = 1
k0 = w/c
beta = w/c*Sin[theta]
k1 = Abs[Sqrt[jdc1]*k0]
k2 = Abs[Sqrt[jdc2]*k0]
gama0 = Abs[Sqrt[k0^2 - beta^2]]
gama1 = Abs[Sqrt[k1^2 - beta^2]]
gama2 = Abs[Sqrt[k2^2 - beta^2]]

rs01 = (gama0 - gama1)/(gama0 + gama1) 
rs02 = (gama0 - gama2)/(gama0 + gama2) 
rp01 = (jdc1*gama0 - gama1)/(jdc1*gama0 + gama1) 
rp02 = (jdc2*gama0 - gama2)/(jdc2*gama0 + gama2) 
ps01 = rs01^2 
ps02 = rs02^2 
pp01 = rp01^2
pp02 = rp02^2 


sprop = (beta*(1 - ps01)*(1 - ps02))/(4*(Abs[1 - rs01*rs02*Exp[I*2*gama0*d]])^2) + (beta*(1 - pp01)*(1 - pp02))/(4*(Abs[1 - rp01*rp02*Exp[I*2*gama0*d]])^2) 
wT1 = h*w/(Exp[h*w/(kB*T1)] - 1) 

wT2 = h*w/(Exp[h*w/(kB*T2)] - 1) 

Qprop = NIntegrate[(wT1 - wT2)*sprop, {w, 0, Infinity}, {theta, 0, 
Pi/2}]
```

Can you please help why I am getting this message?
I found several similar error posts, it seems that it is a numerical accuracy problem, how can I solve it?
Here is the integrate picture:[image][image]

```
NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand ((1.054*10^-34 w)/(-1.+E^(3.81884*10^-15 w))-(1.054*10^-34 w)/(-1.+E^(1.52754*10^-14 w))) ((E^(Im[Sqrt[Plus[<<2>>]]]/250000) w Sin[theta] (1-(<<1>>)^2/(<<1>>)^2) (1+(Times[<<1>>]+<<1>>)^2/(Times[<<1>>]+<<1>>)^2))/(1200000000 Abs[((<<1>>) (<<1>>+<<1>>))/(Plus[<<2>>] <<1>>)]^2)+(E^((Im<<1>><<1>>])/250000) w <<1>> (1-<<1>>) (1+(<<1>>)^2))/(1200000000 Abs[<<1>>]^2)) has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,4.0247*10^31},{0.785398,1.5708}}.
NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand ((1.054*10^-34 w)/(-1.+E^(3.81884*10^-15 w))-(1.054*10^-34 w)/(-1.+E^(1.52754*10^-14 w))) ((E^(Im[Sqrt[Plus[<<2>>]]]/250000) w Sin[theta] (1-(<<1>>)^2/(<<1>>)^2) (1+(Times[<<1>>]+<<1>>)^2/(Times[<<1>>]+<<1>>)^2))/(1200000000 Abs[((<<1>>) (<<1>>+<<1>>))/(Plus[<<2>>] <<1>>)]^2)+(E^((Im<<1>><<1>>])/250000) w <<1>> (1-<<1>>) (1+(<<1>>)^2))/(1200000000 Abs[<<1>>]^2)) has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,4.0247*10^31},{0.785398,1.5708}}.
NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand ((1.054*10^-34 w)/(-1.+E^(3.81884*10^-15 w))-(1.054*10^-34 w)/(-1.+E^(1.52754*10^-14 w))) ((E^(Im[Sqrt[Plus[<<2>>]]]/250000) w Sin[theta] (1-(<<1>>)^2/(<<1>>)^2) (1+(Times[<<1>>]+<<1>>)^2/(Times[<<1>>]+<<1>>)^2))/(1200000000 Abs[((<<1>>) (<<1>>+<<1>>))/(Plus[<<2>>] <<1>>)]^2)+(E^((Im<<1>><<1>>])/250000) w <<1>> (1-<<1>>) (1+(<<1>>)^2))/(1200000000 Abs[<<1>>]^2)) has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,4.0247*10^31},{0.785398,1.5708}}.
General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumri will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Comment: You have a mixture of very large and very small values in your integral.  If you change variable to make `w` smaller by a factor of (say) 10^15, you may have more luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have some unnecessary `FullSimplify` in your code, which will produce numerical instability. For example, evaluating your expression produces a complex number:

```
(wT1 - wT2)*sprop /. {w -> 1, theta -> 1} 
(* 7.29104*10^-30 - 1.11592*10^-29 I *)
```

To resolve this, either remove all `FullSimplify`or integrate only the real part of the expression:

```
Qprop = NIntegrate[
  Re[(wT1 - wT2)*sprop], {w, 0, Infinity}, {theta, 0, Pi/2}]
(* 538.696 *)
```

Even though the integral is evaluated, an error is raised about the failed convergence, so the result is probably wrong.

To get a better idea of what kind of the expression we are integrating, I suggest plotting the expression.

```
Plot3D[Re[(wT1 - wT2)*sprop/h], {w, 0, 50}, {theta, 0, Pi/2}]
```

[image: 3D Plot]

The function seems to be quite well-behaved, but when we increase the range, the functions seems to be unbounded, hence the integral is probably not converging.

[image: 3D Plot]

Are you sure this integral should converge? It might help if you let us know, what exactly your expression represents.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The expression of ` beta ` is right but I still can't get the solution. The warning message remains unchanged.

Comment: I have edited my answer and provided some other ideas that might help you.

Comment: Thank you for your thinking, I suppose the process of ` Sqrt `may has problem, ` Abs ` should add the front of the ` Sqrt `, but the rusult shows "The integrand sprop\ ((1.054*10^-34\w)/(-1.+E^(2.54589*10^-14 \
w))-(1.054*10^-34\w)/(-1.+E^(7.63768*10^-12 w))) has evaluated to \
non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with \
boundaries {{\[Infinity],0.},{0,1.5708}}"